# This database cannnot be imported error after changing connection string to relative path

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, connection-string, relative-path

I am working in Visual Studio 2017 , window forms(c#), I have added database to my project, (New item -> new service based database) and I took this connection string:

[image]

Then I ran this query and it works fine :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Podlaktica40cm\Desktop\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
{
     con.Open();

     using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Test values(45)", con))
     {
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
 }
```

**Problem is**: when I change my connection string's path to be relative instead of absolute, like this:

```
 @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = |DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True")
```

Now when I open database in Visual Studio explorer and try to refresh it, this happens:

[image]

So no rows inserted in my database. I have also tried to change **copy to output directory** property to copy if newer, but still same result.

**NOTE:** I finished my project and I was working with absolute path, I finished all testing and now I have to change to relative path so it could work on other computers, therefore I made this demo test app to show you what is the error and to simplify (ConfigurationManager, parametrised SQL and so on). After I put `|DataDirectory|` in my `conString` and when I close my application, all data which I inserted during runtime is deleted and I'm opening application with empty database. I'm assuming there is some confusion between `.mdf` file in project directory and mdf in debug folder. I'm really confused so any help or any link would be great!

Comment: What path you have in `|DataDirectory|`  ?

Comment: SQL Server is - as the name implies - really a **server-based** product - you should **stop fiddling around** with "free-floating" `.mdf` database file - those are nothing but grief! Put your database **on the server** (where it belongs) and reference it using a **server-oriented** connection string

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it points to /bin/Debug folder

Comment: @marc_s but i just want local database , for one pc

Comment: Make sure the pathname is valid. A you missing a backslash?

Comment: @jdweng im using @ so i only need one backslash, path is fine

Comment: I meant between the folder name and and the filename

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, I don't understand . Can you explain ?

Comment: In the picture above check if the Primary File Path is correct.

Comment: @jdweng , it is , because i got no error during connecting with database

Comment: The relative path is with reference to the location of the executable.  Your mdf file is in same folder as the cs source files.  So path would be ..\..\Database1.mdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurring because I was accessing and inserting data in mdf file in bin/debug folder , whereas I was opening database in source folder of my project via Server Explorer. So I have added another connection with mdf file in debug and all changes are visible there!